# Python Decorator to convert Pandas DataFrame to dict

Tags: python, pandas, python-decorators

How can I create a Python decorator that can wrap any function that returns a Pandas Dataframe, and convert this returned Dataframe into a dictionary of the format:

```
output = {col: list(df[col]) for col in df.columns}
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

def some_func_that_returns_df():
  df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], columns=['a'])
  return df


def wrapper(df: pd.DataFrame):
    _df = {col: df[col].to_list() for col in df.columns}
    return _df

df = wrapper(some_func_that_returns_df()) 
print(df)
>>> {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

However, I would like to achieve this:

```
@df_to_dict
def some_func_that_returns_df():
  df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], columns=['a'])
  return df

df_as_dict = some_func_that_returns_df()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
def df_to_dict(func):
    def to_dict():
        return func().to_dict(orient='list')
    return to_dict

@df_to_dict
def some_func_that_returns_df():
    df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], columns=['a'])
    return df
```

output:

```
>>> some_func_that_returns_df()
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator must return a function.

```
def df_to_dict_decorator(func_that_returns_df):
    def func_that_returns_dict(*args, **kwargs):
        return wrapper(func_that_returns_df(*args, **kwargs)) # this uses your "wrapper" function, consider renaming it to df_to_dict
    return func_that_returns_dict

@df_to_dict_decorator
def foo(df):
    return df
```

Demo:

```
>>> foo(pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3]))
{0: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Also note that DataFrames already have a `.to_dict` method.